# I can populate hidden divs only after the second form submit

Tags: jquery, html, populate, multiple-forms

I can populate hidden divs only after the second form submit. After the first submit there is an error. Why? Using jQuery Form Plugin. Any idea? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// get ID from the form name:
    $('form').submit(function(e){
     targetNum = this.name;
// call processing page:
    $('#formTarget' + targetNum).ajaxForm({ 
// populate DIV
        target: '#divTarget' + targetNum, 
        success: function() { 
            $('#divTarget' + targetNum).fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
    });
});

<div id='divTarget1'></div>
<form id='formTarget1' name='1' action='process2.asp' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='MapaID' value='1'>
<input type='submit' value='OK'>
</form>

<div id='divTarget2'></div>
<form id='formTarget2' name='2' action='process2.asp' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='MapaID' value='2'>
<input type='submit' value='OK'>
</form>

<div id='divTarget3'></div>
<form id='formTarget3' name='3' action='process2.asp' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='MapaID' value='3'>
<input type='submit' value='OK'>
</form>
```

Comment: After the first submit data are not populated to div and user can see the processing page (process2.asp) instead of starting page with forms and hidden divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':submit').click(function(e) {
        targetNum = $('form').has(this).prop('name');
        $('#formTarget' + targetNum).ajaxForm({
            target: '#divTarget' + targetNum,
            success: function() {
                $('#divTarget' + targetNum).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: On `submit()` page reload happen. `return false` statement will stop this page reload.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, 'return false' stops all submits.

Comment: Many, many thanks Abdullah, it works, but without 'return false' line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.load()` method for this.

Comment: Rohan, do you mean to put .load() method  instead of this line:  $('#formTarget' + targetNum).ajaxForm({... I am asking because of curiosity, because problem seems being solved by abudllah.abcoder.

Comment: You can try putting that. Read more about .load() here: http://api.jquery.com/load/ . I guess I got your question correctly :)